# Why does this Neo4j OPTIONAL MATCH returns a null row

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following data model

- Order has an "order_id" attribute, always defined
- An order has multiple OrderLine
- Each OrderLine may have several ManufacturedProduct
- Each ManufacturedProduct may have several WorkOperation

This is the data in the graph for order 2454, it has only 2 OrderLine :

[image]

This is the query I'm running :

```
match (o:Order)--(ol:OrderLine)
where o.order_id = "2454"
optional match (ol)--(mp:ManufacturedProduct)--(wo:WorkOperation)

return o.order_id,
 mp.unique_ref,
 collect(id(wo))
```

Why am I getting 3 rows instead of two, with one containing null values but the order id ? (mp.unique_ref exists for all ManufacturedProduct, the entire object is null not just the attribute)

[image]

Comment: Which query did you use to get the graph for this image? Are you sure there are no other nodes connected?

Comment: There is some `Orderline` node linked to your `Order` node, which has no `ManufacturedProduct`

Comment: Oh you're both right, the query I was using to visualize the graph was doing mandatory matches, not optional ones, and there was an Orderline with no ManufacturedProduct